# Loading one webpage from another webpage

Tags: web-development

I am thinking of ways of adding a "chat bar" onto websites. One idea that I had works like this:

- random site(e.g.): youtube.com/video1
- w/ "chat bar" attached: chatbar.com/youtube-video1

So basically youtube.com/video1 will be loaded by my webpage (with the "chat bar"). I think google image re

Is this even possible? (I'm pretty sure good does something similar when a user clicks a link from image search results) Point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use an IFRAME to put another web page into yours. You won't need to do that with Youtube as you can embed it in your page. (Look on youtube for the embed option under sharing.)

You use an IFRAME like this:

```
<iframe src="chatbar.com/youtube-video1" width="xxx" height="yyy">
</iframe>
```

Where xxx and yyy are the size you want it.

Comment: Almost right, the src should contain the page you wish to frame, not the the page that contains the bar.

Comment: Thanks. What about using php `echo get_file_content('youtube.com/video1')`? Is there any advantage in using Iframe instead of this?

Comment: That's actually a better solution, because it makes it part of the page. Some people may have their browsers configured to block iframes as they are a security risk.